Delete customer records during merge process but save primary record with flag as Y in other table
I have a weird situation where I have one primary table where there is no flag to identify or mark the records for deletion, so I have to rely on the rowid. The table A looks like



Customer_No
IdentityCode
IdentityNumber




1234
passport
ABCDEFGH


1234
passport
ABCDEFGH


1234
adhar
1234 5678 9123


5678
passport
ABCDEFGH



Now when I search the details on my Oracle forms, I use ABCDEFGH and it will show me all the customers having matching records. So the output will be like above but with additional columns(This is my second table B) as



Customer_No
IdentityCode
IdentityNumber
maintain
Remove
n_merge_seq




1234
passport
ABCDEFGH
Yes
No
1


1234
passport
ABCDEFGH
No
Yes
1


1234
adhar
1234 5678 9123
Yes
No
1


5678
passport
ABCDEFGH
No
Yes
1



There is a third table C which stores only customer number and flags as below. Only one customer can be maintain.



Customer_no
Maintain
Remove
n_merge_seq




1234
Y
N
1


5678
N
Y
1



I cannot delete the data from TableB as this is audit table and same applies for TableC.
I used min(rowid) to keep only the min rowid record for each customer_no||identity code||IdentityNumber where B.maintain = Yes and C.maintain = Y
cursor cr_save_Y is
      SELECT  y.n_cust_ref_no,y.v_iden_code,y.v_iden_no,MIN(z.rowid) row_idn
        FROM  TableC x,
              TableB   y,
              TableA z
        WHERE x.customer_no     = y.customer_no
        AND   x.n_merge_seq  = y.n_merge_seq
        AND   y.identitycode       = z.identitycode
        AND   y.identitynumber         = z.identitynumber
        AND   y.customer_no     = z.customer_no
        AND   NVL(y.v_maintain,'Y')='Y'     ---iden no to keep  
        AND   x.n_merge_cust_seq   = 1
GROUP BY y.customer_no,
      y.identitycode,
      y.identitynumber   ;

Then I am looping it like below
 for i in cr_save_Y
         loop
                  
            delete from TableA
            where customer_no = i.customer_no
            and identitycode = i.identitycode 
            and identityNumber = i.identityNumber 
            and rowid <> i.row_idn;
            
         end loop;  

Till here, its fine because if row_id does not matches, my records are saved. The issue comes with the next code of line. In the below code, I am deleting the data from TableA where if record is either maintain or remove = 'Y', fetch the record and delete the exact record.
delete from TableA
    where customer_no||identitycode||identitynumber in (select y.customer_no||y.identitycode||y.identitynumber
from TableC x,TableB y
where x.customer_no=y.customer_no
and x.n_merge_seq=y.n_merge_seq                                                 and nvl(y.maintain,'N')='N'                                                 and x.n_merge_seq=1 
and (x.maintain = 'Y' or x.remove='Y'); 

But as I cannot delete data from TableB, it still has record where 1234||passport||ABCDEFGH will be fetched as per the above query because tableB.maintain = N and TableC.maintain = Y. so this record will get matched to my tableA record 1234||passport||ABCDEFGH and this way, both the records are now deleted and I am left with nothing.
Lets assume, I write the code like below
delete from TableA
    where customer_no||identitycode||identitynumber in (select y.customer_no||y.identitycode||y.identitynumber
from TableC x,TableB y
where x.customer_no=y.customer_no
and x.n_merge_seq=y.n_merge_seq                                                 and nvl(y.maintain,'N')='N'                                                 and x.n_merge_seq=1 
and (x.remove='Y');

Then also, it will not solve the purpose in the below case



Customer_No
IdentityCode
IdentityNumber




1234
passport
ABCDEFGH


1234
adhar
1234 5678 9123


5678
passport
ABCDEFGH






Customer_No
IdentityCode
IdentityNumber
maintain
Remove
n_merge_seq




1234
passport
ABCDEFGH
Yes
No
1


1234
adhar
1234 5678 9123
No
Yes
1


5678
passport
ABCDEFGH
No
Yes
1



In this way, it will only fetch 5678||passport||ABCDEFGH and delete it, but my other record 1234||adhar||123456789123 will not be deleted.
Is there any way to satisfy both the scenerios? The above sql query fails because if I choose both maintain and remove, then I have fear of both records being deleted.
I need the output like below
Scenario 1:



Customer_No
IdentityCode
IdentityNumber




1234
passport
ABCDEFGH


1234
adhar
1234 5678 9123



Scenario 2:



Customer_No
IdentityCode
IdentityNumber




1234
passport
ABCDEFGH




Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; the full PL/SQL blocks you are using (not just partial snippets); and an English (not code) explanation of the logic you are trying to implement. At the moment, you talk about what you are trying to do in terms of the code that doesn't work rather than trying to describe what the outcome and logic should be which makes it difficult to follow what you are trying to achieve; instead give us a simple English description of the process you are trying to implement.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Did you think about removing duplicate rows from table A. There is no purpose of having 2 or more identical rows in the table. That could  couse only problems. Maybe the best thing to do here is reducing your table A to distinct rows - deleting duplicate rows:
Delete From tbl_a
Where rowid NOT IN  ( Select   Min( ROWID )
                      From     tbl_a
                      Group By Customer_No, IdentityCode, IdentityNumber
                    );

Update:
If you can not delete from table A (as commented) then you could have an SQL that will flag the rows differently. I'm not sure what you realy want to do, since there is no explanation about it - there is just the explanation of your code which doesn't say anything about the logic and/or about the expectation. Anyway, maybe the code bellow could help you make a distinction between the identical rows in table A:
--      S Q L : 
WITH
  cte_bc AS  -- this is your subquery (adjusted to sample data in the fiddle) from your 1st Delete command posted
    ( Select      b.Customer_No, b.identitycode, b.IdentityNumber
      From        tbl_c c
      Inner Join  tbl_b b ON( c.Customer_No = b.Customer_No And
                              c.n_merge_seq = b.n_merge_seq And 
                              Nvl(b.Maintain,'NO') = 'NO'   And 
                              c.n_merge_seq = 1 ) 
      Where       c.Maintain = 'Y' Or b.Remove = 'YES'
    ), 
  cte_a AS
    ( Select   a.*, 
               ROWNUM as row_num, 
               Min(ROWNUM) 
                   Over(Partition By a.Customer_No, a.IdentityCode, a.IdentityNumber
                   Order By a.Customer_No, a.IdentityCode, a.IdentityNumber) as rn
      From     tbl_a a
      Order By a.Customer_No, a.IdentityCode, a.IdentityNumber
    )
Select    a.*, 
          Case When a.row_num = RN Or bc.Customer_No Is Null Then 'NO' Else 'YES' End as delete_flag,
          Case When a.row_num = RN Or bc.Customer_No Is Null Then 'YES' Else 'NO' End as opposite_delete_flag 
From      cte_a a
Left Join cte_bc bc ON( a.Customer_No = bc.Customer_No And 
                         a.IdentityCode = bc.IdentityCode And 
                         a.IdentityNumber = bc.IdentityNumber)
Order By   a.row_num

R e s u l t :



CUSTOMER_NO
IDENTITYCODE
IDENTITYNUMBER
ROW_NUM
RN
DELETE_FLAG
OPPOSITE_DELETE_FLAG




1234
passport
ABCDEFGH
1
1
NO
YES


1234
passport
ABCDEFGH
2
1
YES
NO


1234
adhar
1234 5678 9123
3
3
NO
YES


5678
passport
ABCDEFGH
4
4
NO
YES



fiddle

Cannot delete data from the tableA that is the issue.

Thanks for the explanation, I will try to do this. The logic is, Check maintain = Y in table C and maintain = Y in Table B, these rows should be saved and maintain = N should be deleted from TableA. The issue comes when there are identical rows in tableA for which one row has maintain = N and maintain = Y in table B.

@Gajendra Still don't get it what you want to do or get. Show us your expected result with this data. In question you say - can not delete from audit tables B and C,  in comment you say can not delete from table A. Your code has Delete From tableA, though. This is confusing all together.
